# Flex DropDownList Hightlight

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I am trying to Skin a "hightlight" of a DropDownList item. I can not find any documentation on changing the skin of the items hightlight / rollover skin. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!
Michael

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom item renderer (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS77c1dbb1bd80d38313b7ce1c129eb7d5e04-8000.html)) and set `autoDrawBackground` to `false` for it. Then use states as in a link above and define your graphics for `hovered` state.

P.S. The valid states for item renderer are: `selected`, `hovered`, `normal`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work, however, the graphic shows up as the "normal" state, and i'm not sure how to define it as the "hovered" state

Comment: Do you know how to use states in Flex 4?

Comment: Right. Please read it. This knowledge is one of the must have in Flex development.